# I accidentally deleted windows 8.1 while while installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows

I am very new to Ubuntu, i started using Ubuntu just two months ago and it's been really awesome until last night when an annoying problem came up, Ubuntu graphics fails when booting, sometimes comes with a blank screen and just leave me hanging without a blinking cursor. Trying to re-install Ubuntu, i accidentally deleted Windows 8.1 and all partitions with windows recovery area all gone. I really would love to keep my windows OS while running more of my everyday tasks on Ubuntu. Lost data on windows are safe in cloud, i just want to have my Windows 8 back as dual boot option while Ubuntu does all my tasks. Is there any way i can re-install or recover Windows without buying a new Installation CD? Would a trial windows version automatically extend the key? The warranty on the laptop is expired, Would Lenovo help desk provide me with a new Windows license key? I am stuck and need all kinds of help to make this trouble go away. Please help!

I use a Lenovo G580, 500 Gigs i-7 processor, 8 gigs RAM with pre-installed windows 8.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu). Some laptops come with a recovery partition used for restoring the laptop back to the way it was when it was shipped from the factory. If your laptop came with a recovery partition and you recover the recovery partition, then maybe you can restore Windows 8 using the recovery partition.

Comment: Recovery should start when pressing F10 during boot

Comment: No, it didn't come with a recovery partion. I have to create a One-Key recovery backup CD/USb or in the lenovo cloud which i never did because i could easily do a clean install or system restore whenever the windows settings doesn't work fine. My bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call Lenovo and tell them what happened. They should provide you with a recovery CD. I had a similar situation with my Asus some time ago and they sent me a recovry CD for like $10. Another option would be to download a trial edition of windows 8.1 then enter the activation code that's usually located on the physical machine somewhere. Unfortunately any documents and games you had on there prior to deleting windows are gone so you won't be able to recover them but at least you will have windows.

Comment: I really won't bother about the data though, i just want the windows back, up and running.Windows 8 activation key is embedded somewhere in the BIOS. Would give all options a try.

Answer (score 1):

lil late but i felt i would share this..
found myself in a similar position..u can use this to download your windows back from ms

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media